# Tooltip in jquery customizing style

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I need to customize a specific tooltip when I hover over elements that includes an image and text(includes frame and arrow). I am using this function:

```
 $( document ).tooltip({
                items: ".links",

                content: function() {
                    var $this = $( this),,html="";
                    var frame = "<div class='tooltip'>";
                    var lowertext = "<div class ='tooltiptext'>press here</div>"

                    html = "<img src="http://image.com" height="60" width="80">";//this is the image

                    return frame+html+lowertext"</div>";
                }
            });
```

I am able to show the image with the text but now I need a arrow to point to the text with a white frame. something like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Here is my jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyy3G/)

Comment: You will have to provide fiddle for this so any one can help you

Comment: What did you meant by white frame?